# Android Database Connectivity

Tags: java, php, android, database

I am new in android development and I am creating an android app.

When user click on login I should receive its data on my database.

I think I have a problem in android database connectivity: when I click on login I receive no data in my database.

I use XAMPP for database.

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                String result = "Database connection successful";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Insert into login  VALUES(?, ?)");
                ps.setString(1, email.getText().toString());
                ps.setString(2, password.getText().toString());
                ps.executeUpdate();


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } //end of insert button calling
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //to Fetch the Record
            //finish();

            login();

        }
    });
```

Comment: i want when user click on login to enter in my app i receive it on my admin page

Comment: basically i want to make my xampp database connectivity with android..

Comment: You add some records in your database. You add an extra one query.

Comment: no am not indian

Comment: okay what is your login script language.

Comment: i make table in xampp for record but the problem which i face is the connectiviy of xampp with android

Comment: my login language is java

Comment: java for back end and XML for front end

Comment: if you got my point then please help me

Comment: this is my library which i add in gradle build ........  compile project (':mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin')

Comment: You use php for login. because if you add you application in google playstore and you change your server then your app goes to error

Comment: Use Firebase for login, database, storage - its free, its simple, its awesme

Comment: my country is  Pakistan

Comment: would you please like to  tell me how o use Firebase database. its built in in android studio??

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, you want to add some modularity to your application's architecture. Typically, the authentication logic will not be implemented inside your android application, but rather in a separate module. For instance, inside a PHP file that resides in your server:

1. Read the username and password in your app
2. POST them to the PHP file
3. The PHP file reads from the database, checks if the credentials are correct, and returns either a success message (plus user information if applicable) or an error.
4. In your application, your get the returned value from the PHP file, then you decide what to do (typically you will either move the user to the next activity or display some error message).

You may want to have a look at this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm